# Which image formats are supported by WMTS server?

Tags: wmts

I know WMTS sever delivers tiles. I am creating a generic WMTS client. I have following questions:

1) As per OpenGIS® Web Map Tile Service Implementation Standard, WMTS server can deliver tiles in which format?

2) How can I know the the supported image format which server supports through getcapabily request?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no required format for WMTS services, all you can do is request the getcapabilities document and then for each layer there are one or more `<Format>` blocks that you should look for to tell you what formats are available for that layer:

```
    <Layer>
      <ows:Title>OS OpenData Raster (greyscale)</ows:Title>
      <ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
        <ows:LowerCorner>-179.8425860941661 -89.92400664174129</ows:LowerCorner>
        <ows:UpperCorner>179.97997214501078 89.99264625256251</ows:UpperCorner>
      </ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
      <ows:Identifier>sf:osopenrasterbw</ows:Identifier>
      <Style isDefault="true">
        <ows:Identifier/>
      </Style>
      <Format>image/png</Format>
      <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
```

Answer (score 1):

Section 11.3 of the WMTS spec (07-057r7) suggests but does not require that servers offer at least one of `image/png` or `image/jpeg` and that clients support both.  WMTS does not restrict the allowed tile formats though so a server could advertise whatever it wants and it's up to the client to look at the capabilities document to decide which option works best, if any.  If none work then it should produce a suitable error (None of the tile formats offered by the server `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet`, `audio/flac`, `application/pgp-signature` are supported)